# Examples of the situations where the use of Plain Old Data is must?

Tags: c++

> A union in C++98 cannot contain a class that has virtual functions or
>   nontrivial constructors or destructors.

what are the situations you know where the use of [POD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_old_data_structure) is must?

Comment: For a start, whenever you interface a "lower-level" component (graphics, metadata, audio) etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

parsing some structures in binary files, for example

Comment: How much real advantage is there to parsing a binary file by overlaying it with a PODS, versus using functions like `int get_int16(uint8_t char **pp, uint8_t *end_of_buffer) {unsigned char *p = *pp; if (p+2 <= end_of_buffer) {*pp = p+22; return p[0]+256*p[1];} else {handle error}}` to parse out the data?  Note that unlike the PODS-based approach, the function-based approach is byte-order agnostic.

Answer (score 2):

The syntax

```
X a = {1, 2, 3};
```

only works with PODs, although this restriction is lifted with `std::initializer_list` in C++11.

Comment: Aggregate initialisation requires `X` to be an aggregate type, not necessarily POD.

Comment: @Cheers You are always welcome to correct factual errors in my answers.

Answer (score 2):

When interacting with a non C++ API (typically a C style API).

Comment: Uhm, no, although the types required by any existing C interface are necessarily POD. For example, you can pass pointers to non-POD types, plus pointers to functions that operate on values, to C code. Which is then happy.

Answer (score 2):

One case where PODness is required is for direct conversion to/from sequence of bytes.

Another case where PODness is required is where the type must guarantee that instantiation has no effect whatsoever other than using a bit of memory, e.g. as in the following class:

```
namespace detail {
    using std::vector;

    template< class Type, Podness::Enum podNess = Podness::isPod >
    class ValueWrapper_
    {
    private:
        Type    v_;

    public:
        Type const& ref() const { return v_; }

        ValueWrapper_() {}       // No initialization
        ValueWrapper_( Type const v ): v_( v ) {}
    };

    template< class Type >
    struct ValueWrapper_< Type, Podness::isNotPod >
    {
    private:
        vector<Type>    v_;     // General but incurs allocation overhead.

    public:
        Type const& ref() const { return v_[0]; }

        ValueWrapper_() {}       // Supports apparent no initialization.
        ValueWrapper_( Type const v ): v_( 1, v ) {}
    };
}    // namespace detail

template< class Type >
class Optional_
{
private:
    typedef detail::ValueWrapper_<Type, Podness_<Type>::value > Wrapper;

    Wrapper const   value_;
    bool const      isNone_;

    Optional_& operator=( Optional_ const& );         // No such.

public:
    bool isNone() const { return isNone_; }

    Type const& value() const
    {
        hopefully( !isNone_ )
            || throwX( "Optional_::value(): there is no value" );
        return value_.ref();
    }

    Optional_(): isNone_( true ) {}
    Optional_( Type const& v ): value_( v ), isNone_( false ) {}

    static Optional_ none() { return Optional_(); }
};

template<>
class Optional_< void >
{
private:
    Optional_& operator=( Optional_ const& );         // No such.

public:
    bool isNone() const { return true; }

    void value() const
    {
        throwX( "Optional_::value(): there is no value" );
    }

    Optional_() {}
    static Optional_ none() { return Optional_(); }
};
```

Hm, I can't think of any third case…

Answer (score 1):

Parsing comms protocols is another one.